# Cannot read property 'addGraph' of undefined in meteorJS - nvd3

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nvd3.js

Using the official nvd3 package (https://atmospherejs.com/nvd3/nvd3)

I have the following code under the Template.rendered block:

```
var formattedEarnedData = formatEarnedData(userEarnedDataSet);

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var earnedChart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .margin({ left: 25 })
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .transition()
        .duration(350)
        .showLegend(true)
        .showYAxis(true)
        .showXAxis(true);

    earnedChart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('Date')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

    earnedChart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Earned')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

    d3.select('#earned-charts svg').datum(
        [{
            key: 'Earned',
            values: formattedEarnedData
        }]
    ).call(earnedChart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(earnedChart.update);

    return earnedChart;
});
```

The following lies at the bottom of the js file outside of the rendered block:

```
    var formatEarnedData = function(dataSet) {
    var earnedDataArray = new Array();
    var groupedDates = _.groupBy(_.pluck(dataSet, 'progression'), function(date) {
    return moment(date).format('MMM D');
});

_.each(_.values(groupedDates), function(dates) {
    earnedDataArray.push({
        date: dates[0],
        total: dates.length
    });
});

return earnedDataArray;
}
```

Even after following the documentation, I am still getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'addGraph' of undefined
```

Can any nvd3 experts shed some light on why this error is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include `<link href="nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` and
`<script src="nv.d3.min.js"></script>` somewhere in your html as is instructed in the `usage` section?

Comment: Im using meteorJS framework. it running as a packaging. have u tried ?

Comment: I know, read the package documentation.

Comment: @challett but when i revert back with older version meteorJs like <1.8 it working

Comment: Perhaps they changed the way their package interacts with that version of meteor but if you look at the current documentation that you linked it says to include the code I mentioned right at the top of the page under usage